# Ленивая подгрузка сообщений из базы

Tags: jquery, php, javascript, mysql

Всем привет!

Заметил такую проблему, которая мешает удобству на сайте.

Происходит подгрузка дополнительных сообщений (по 10 штук) в div. Если перейти далее (по ссылке) и после нажать назад (в браузере), то подгруженные сообщения ранее исчезают, не отображаются. Их приходится подгружать заново. На многих сайта (примерно с такой же системой) работает без такой проблемы. Подгрузка осуществляется путем скролла. Скорее всего проблема решается с помощью кеширования, но это всего лишь догадки.

Код:

javascript:

```
<script>
var thisPageNum = 1;
var thisWork = 1;

function getNextP() {
    if (thisWork == 1) {
        thisWork = 0;
        $.get("/load?page=" + thisPageNum <?
        if (isset($_GET['sorting'])) echo '&sorting='.$_GET['sorting']; ?> , function (data) {
            $("#LoadNew").html($("#LoadNew").html() + " " + data);
            thisPageNum = thisPageNum + 1;
            thisWork = 1;

            if (data == "") {
                thisWork = 0;
                $('#TheEnd').css('display', 'block');
            }
        });
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    var scrH = $(window).height();
    var scrHP = $("#container").height();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scro = $(this).scrollTop();
        var scrHP = $("#container").height();
        var scrH2 = 0;
        scrH2 = scrH + scro;
        var leftH = scrHP - scrH2;

        if (leftH < 300) {
            getNextP();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML. Выводится 10 первых сообщений путем foreach. После цикла php идет див для подгрузки новых сообщений:

```
<div id="LoadNew"></div>
<div id="TheEnd"> Сообщений больше нет.</div>
```

Comment: 1. Для начала сделайте код читабельным, а не все в одну строку

2. Не стоит мешать JS и PHP код

Comment: Стоит заметить, здесь выполняется ajax запрос, а не смесь php и javascript.

Comment: И в принципе, в этом случает цитированный мною код мало важен. Код работает стабильно, но нужен вариант решения указанной мною проблемы.

Comment: А что же тогда это, как не смесь JS и PHP?

    $.get("/load?page="+thisPageNum<? if(isset($_GET['sorting'])) echo '&sorting=' . $_GET['sorting']; ?>

Comment: Поясняю: `$.get("/load?page="+thisPageNum` - это аякс запрос на jquery. 

`<? if(isset($_GET['sorting'])) echo '&sorting=' . $_GET['sorting']; ?>` - дополнительная часть к аякс запросу. В зависимости от адреса сайта, $_GET параметр передавать в аяксе (для сортировки). Вполне нормальный код. А как по вашем вставить в аякс запрос $.get и передать php файлу данные из $_GET?

Comment: Парсить адресную строку средствами js или хранить в каком-нибудь скрытом поле значение и забирать его так же средствами js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте хеш. Т.е. на кнопках постранички ставите, к примеру ID, в котором есть номер страницы, а в JS по клику вытаскиваете этот номер страницы и устанавливаете хеш. Например, у вас кнопки постранички имеют класс *paginal* и ID pn-1, pn-2 и т.д.:

```
$('.paginal').click(function(e){
    var arrId = $(this).attr("id").split('-');
    var numPage = parseInt(arrId[1], 10); // Номер страницы, можно использовать для чего-то еще
    location.hash = "pn" + numPage; // Устанавливаем хеш
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. Довольно хорошая идея. Но не знаю, кто кого понял. Зачем тут событие клика? В принципе мне нужно восстанавливать все ранее подгрузившие сообщения, после того как я перейду на следующую страницу (любую), нажав на кнопку назад все ранее подгруженные сообщения должны остаться. Вы это так поняли?=) Либо чего то я не до понял, но суть уловил. =)

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите что-бы страницу генерировал сервер - используйте сессии, т.е., например - добавьте в сессию массив вида:

```
 $_SESSION[ 'messages' ] = array('article_id' => 0, 'article_id' => 0, ...);
```

Когда тяните сообщения аяксом - делайте инкремент для каждого элемента массива (по id текущей статьи, или что там у вас). Во время генерации html страницы - проверяйте нет ли в сессии числа для текущей статьи, если нету - выводите страницу по умолчанию, если есть - изменяйте соответствующим образом количество сообщений. Т.е. что-то типа:

```
$id = !empty($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0
                                                             ? $_GET['id'] : 0;
if( $id ) {
  /* db connection here... */
  $step = 10; // количество по умолчанию
  $limit = !empty($_SESSION[ 'messages' ][ $id ])
                           ? $_SESSION[ 'message' ][ $id ] * $step : $step;
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM .... WHERE id=' . (int) $id . ' LIMIT ' . $limit;
  // ......
}
```

Но тут есть небольшой недостаток - если пользователь закроет браузер, сами понимаете - сессия умирает и, соответственно информация не запоминается. Таким образом если вы хотите что-бы эти данные хранились дольше - проделывайте примерно то-же самое только непосредственно в БД с конкретным пользователем. Но тут недостаток в том что не будет работать для незарегистрированных.

По поводу предложения [@Deonis](/users/4058/deonis) - это очень удобно т.к. не требует от вас переписывания серверного кода и решает проблемы гостей и закрытия сессий. Но здесь, все-же, абсолютно разные подходы и в одной задаче будет лучше одно, в иной - другое, соответственно выбирайте то что лучше для решения непосредственно вашей задачи.

Comment: Благодарю. Ценная информация. Все же, если есть возможность не использовать дополнительные запросы к базе, то лучше воздерживаться лишних запросов. Но метод как вариант довольно неплох. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы предполагаете, что пользователь будет несколько раз возвращаться на какую-то страницу, можно сделать так, чтобы при подгрузке в куках сохранялось число, указывающее на то, сколько было подгрузок. Напишите сценарий, который, ориентируясь на число в куках, делал бы определенное количество подгрузок при загрузке страницы.

Comment: К сожалению куки крайне не надежное хранилище информации

Comment: А почему, скажите пожалуйста?
Да и в этой ситуации не требуется ничего выдающегося, думаю